# Question about a set sandwiched between measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Q) Let $E,A_n,B_n$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $A_n\subset E\subset B_n$ and let $A_n, B_n$ be measurable. Let $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(B_n\setminus A_n) = 0$$ Is $E$ measurable? $\mu$ is a generic measure.

I know from a theorem in Rudin that if $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, with $\mathcal{\hat{M}}$ the collection of all $E\subset X$ such that there exist $A,B\in \mathcal{M}$ with $A\subset E\subset B$ and $\mu(B\setminus A)=0$, then $\mathcal{\hat{M}}$ is a sigma algebra and we can define $\mu(E)=\mu(A)$. I understood the proof of it and am looking for a hint on how to approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: One short hint would be to think about $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$.

Comment: Are you aware that the Lebesgue measurable sets form a strictly larger class than the Borel measurable sets, and what the difference between the two is?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, yes, I know that the cardinality of Borel measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$ and that of Lebesgue measurable sets is $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ because |Cantor set| = $\mathfrak{c}$ and all subsets of a Cantor set need to be Lebesgue measurable, so |Lebesgue measurable sets| = $2^\mathfrak{c}$. But I don't see how I can apply that here?

Comment: Take $E$ to be a Lebesgue-but-not-Borel measurable set sandwiched between two Borel sets of the same measure, and have that as your limit.

Comment: I see, thanks, let me try that.